# "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'" turns to "KeyError: (slice(None, None, None), None)" after replacing the ".values"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

there.I'm new to pandas.Appreciated it ahead if you could help me!

1. At first,when running the code using pandas

> `plt.plot(np.arange(len(gain_array)) + 1,`
>
> `df.rolling(rolling_intv, min_periods=1).mean(), 'b')`
>
> `plot_gain(gain_his_ratio)`

it showed the following error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 197, in <module> plot_gain(gain_his_ratio)`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 27, in plot_gain plt.plot(np.arange(len(gain_array)) + 1, df.rolling(rolling_intv, min_periods=1).mean(), 'b')`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2842, in plot **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__ yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 389, in _plot_args y = _check_1d(tup[-1])`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1318, in _check_1d ndim = x[:, None].ndim`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__ indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 358, in get_loc raise KeyError(key)`
>
> `KeyError: (slice(None, None, None), None)`

2. Then after using ".values"
   the error changed like the following:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 224, in <module> plot_gain(gain_his_ratio)`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 44, in plot_gain plt.plot(np.arange(len(gain_array)) + 1, df.rolling(rolling_intv, min_periods=1).mean(), 'b')`
>
> `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'`

3. However,trying to solve the newly emerged problem,I used the `.iloc[:,:0]`.The first problem reappeared!!!
   Here are the  error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 224, in <module> plot_gain(gain_his_ratio)`
>
> `File "D:/anaconda/DROO/optimization.py", line 44, in plot_gain plt.plot(np.arange(len(gain_array)) + 1, df.rolling(rolling_intv, min_periods=1).mean(), 'b')`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2842, in plot **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__ yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 389, in _plot_args y = _check_1d(tup[-1])`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1318, in _check_1d ndim = x[:, None].ndim`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__ indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)`
>
> `File "D:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 358, in get_loc raise KeyError(key)`
>
> `KeyError: (slice(None, None, None), None)`

Therefore,it can be inferenced that the second solution turned to be wrong!
I have no idea with the proper solution,I'd appreciate it if anybody can help me!
I know my skill for editing the problem is quite bad,but I'll gradually learn how to be better!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ok.Sorry ,  I've never ask question here before , therefore dont know how to edit my question,I'll try.